# Facebook page duplicated by hacker

Tags: facebook

My Facebook page has been duplicated by a hacker. I deleted my own Facebook page thinking that would also delete the hackers as well, but it did not work; it only removed mine and left the hacker's duplicate page of me.

I want to delete this faux Facebook page of myself. What can I do?

Comment: Is this your normal Facebook profile or a fan page?

Comment: this is my normal Facebook profile only hacker changed it a little using my profile information

Answer (score 2):

You can try [**reporting** the profile to Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/help/181495968648557):

[image]